# How to use a static member-struct in multiple source files?

Tags: c++, gcc, struct, static-members

I need to use a struct, that is a static member of my class, in multiple source files.  Here's a trimmed down example:

**Header File**

```
namespace NS {
  class Foo {
    public:
    static struct Bar {
      bool test = false;
      uint32_t value; // uninitialized
    } bar; 
  };
}
```

**Source File 1**

```
#include "myHeader.hpp"

using namespace NS;

Foo::Bar Foo::bar;

/* the rest of my first source file */
```

This seems to work without any problems until I add a second source file.

**Source File 2**

```
#include "myHeader.hpp"

using namespace NS;

Foo::Bar Foo::bar;

/* the rest of my second source file */
```

Upon adding the struct to the second source file, I get a "multiple definition" error.  Does anyone know how to make this work, so that a static member-struct can be used in multiple source files?

Comment: Should only need to define `Foo::bar` in one file. Linker will handle the rest.

Comment: It makes no sense to define the object in multiple sources. There is only one object `Foo::bar`. Only one. What are you trying to achieve? `Does anyone know how to make this work` - make what work, exactly? `can be used` you can remove `Foo::Bar Foo::bar;` from `Source File 2` and still use `Foo::bar` in it.

Comment: @user4581301 It was a simple misunderstanding on my part.  Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-definition-rule applies to static data members as well. There is supposed to be only *one* definition of the form

```
Foo::Bar Foo::bar;
```

You can choose in which translation unit (`.cpp` file) you put it, but you must put it in *exactly one* of them.

This has nothing to do with whether `Foo::bar` can be *used* in a given translation unit. For that the *declaration*, included from the header file, is sufficient.